# Tempo de execução do código

Tags: python-3.x

Boa noite, o que eu poderia fazer para saber o tempo de cada iteração que o meu código faz?
Pesquisando um pouco achei o comando time.time(), mas quando o uso em meu código obtenho apenas resultados 0.0. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Segue a implementação do meu código:

```
x_values = []
def eq_diff3(V):
    return -V/10
values_dt = [0.01,0.1,1,2,10]
T = 50
for dt in values_dt:
    start = time.time() #Começa contando aqui
    V0 = 50
    t = np.linspace(0,T,int(T/dt)+1)
    x = np.zeros(len(t))
    x[0] = V0    
    for i in range(1,len(t)):
        start = time.time()        
        x[i] = x[i-1] + eq_diff3(x[i-1])*dt    
    vm_all.append(x)
    x_values.append(t)
    end = time.time() # termina de contar aqui
    duration = end - start 
    print(duration) #printa quanto tempo demorou
```

Saída:

```
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
```

Comment: O número tente a ser bem pequeno mesmo: https://ideone.com/vCU99h. Verifique quais são os valores de `start` e `end` individualmente.

Comment: Obrigado, eu modifiquei o codigo para printar primeiro o valor de star e depois o valor de end como você sugeriu. Obtive o seguinte para o primeiro loop:
valor de start é: 1599744343.5452778
valor de end é: 400.4330963
O que isso significa?

Comment: O site que você mandou está me dizendo o tempo de cada loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o `timeit`, ele é mais preciso do que o `time` para trecho de códigos rápidos.

```
import timeit

tempo_inicial = timeit.default_timer()

print('Olá Mundo!')

tempo_final = timeit.default_timer()

print('Tempo Total:', tempo_final - tempo_inicial)
```

Além disso, dentro do seu loop for tem uma linha `start = time.time()`, acho que você precisa remover essa linha.

Comment: Olá, obrigado pela resposta. Eu modifiquei o código a cima e obtive as seguintes saídas
-1599743943.112952
-1599743943.1129992
-1599743943.1123936
-1599743943.1121457
-1599743943.1130106

O que eu preciso ver são as números depois das casas decimais? Qual a unidade de tempo disso? Obrigado.

Comment: Estranho que deu números negativos, deveria dar um resultado parecido com "Tempo Total: 0.00013969999999999955" em segundos. Dentro do seu loop for tem uma linha "start = time.time()", acho que você precisa remover essa linha.

Comment: Ah, legal. Foi erro meu mesmo. Agora obtive os valores:

0.006424300000162475;
0.0015780999999606138;
0.00027569999997467676;
0.00019210000004932226;
0.00013030000013714016;

Comment: Que bom que deu certo, eu editei a resposta.